# Laravel: What's the best way to delete a row in a pivot table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have 3 models inside a Laravel application:

- `User`
- `Question`
- `Alternative`

Some model relations:

1. `Question` can have many `Alternative`.
2. `Alternative` belongs to one `Question`

There's a pivot table which stores **an answer** by an user. It stores the `user_id` and the `alternative_id`.

In the pivot table, how can I delete all answers from a specific `Question`? (I have the `question_id`)

Comment: Please provide code for each model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use detach as well sync method but you have to define relationships first in your models e.g

```
public class Question extends Model {
    public function alternatives() {
       return $this->hasMany(Alternative::class);
    }
}


public class Alternative extends Model {
    public function users() {
       return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

and than

```
$question = Question::findOrFail('question_id');

$question->alternative()->user()->sync();
```

or

```
$question->alternative()->user()->detach();
```

Comment: Even though this didn't answer directly to my question, it led me to the right solution. Also, it's the clearer answer at the moment.

Comment: Glad to be helpful.